# Transcriptome analysis

Tags: r, rna-seq, genomics, rna, metagenome

I am trying to assemble reads belonging to two different readlength. Is it a valid way since I am looking for common genes among the species I am assembling.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My work focuses on identifying common genes amongst different species of insects. I am doing transcriptome analysis to find these genes. However, I am assembling reads from different readlength using Trinity. I am unable to understand how to proceed next.